# GCC / GNU Assembler x86 force all calls in function to be absolute addressing

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, gnu-assembler

I have a function which I copy to the heap, I want all calls to other functions in this function to generate opcodes 9A or FF for absolute calls, instead of the default opcode E8 which is a relative call, for obvious reasons

ARM and some other platforms seems to have an option -mlong-calls, which seems to do something similar, but this is not available for x86

x86-64 has the option -mcmodel=large which also seems to generate other opcodes, this is not available for x86 when compiling with -m32

How can this be achieved on x86 with gcc / gas?

Comment: I feel this is an xy-question, where this is part of "a way to do something", rather than the end goal. Clarify your end goal, and it'll give you a better answer. What are you actually trying to achieve? In general, absolute calls are a pain to deal with, because they need relocation on loading, where relative calls don't, so relative calls are preferred. And compiler will be the one deciding this, although in SOME cases, it's possible to change those decisions in the linker.

Comment: You do realize, as well, that the calls you're requestion are "far" calls, in other words, use a segment as well as an absolute address? (Just looking through the LLVM instruction tables, to see what that does) - as far as I can tell, LLVM will only [if it's at all possible] with inline assembler, never generated by the compiler.

Comment: I'm creating a generic trampoline function which is called when a function is hooked, I'm already detecting a few bytes in each copy which I change depending on what it is suppose to do for example the number of arguments, argument type detection and original function. And I thought I narrow down the question to a very specific problem in hope of getting a better answer, since this is the only question I need answered right now, x86 has support for this kind of stuff. Hmm but relocation might be a big problem as you said. The other option for me is to detect all calls, and rewrite them on heap

Comment: After a second thought relocation on load should be fine, I just need the linker to make those addresses absolute with relocation when it is loaded and all should be fine and very easy to continue from there

Comment: Like I said, you probably can't even generate those instructions in gcc other than as inline assembler (and calls from inline assembler gets "interesting"). You will also need to know what code-segment you are going to, and make sure the return is a "far return" (so it pops the segment from the stack), or stuff will go really interesting real quick... I'm pretty sure that's not what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up on the far return, haven't catch that before. Would I need far return for "FF /2, CALL r/m32, Call near, absolute indirect, address given in r/m32" which states its a near but still absolute? I might make my own dynamic linker / loader and just detect all calls and rewrite all addresses for each copy

Comment: `r/m32` is a "register or memory address to be used as the target for the operation", meaning if the absolute address is 0x1000, your code will read from 0x1000 to find where to jump. I don't think this is what you want either. And I'm reasonably sure that you do NOT want absolute addresses anyway - why would you want to jump to an absolute address that is stored in the code itself? If that's what you actually want, you're probably looking for "function pointer" (and the compiler will do the right thing there already, no need for special options). Again, explain what it is you're trying to do!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132975/discussion-between-markus-and-mats-petersson).

Comment: Not keen on being personal advisor. Please redo your question with some code example of what you're actually trying to achieve, and then we can probably find a solution. x86 does not have an instruction that calls an absolute address without segments, or using indirection [register or memory containing the target address]. You can of course do `mov $0x1234, eax; call eax`